# Print polynomial in variable format in python

Tags: python, polynomials

```
from numpy import linalg,dot
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
x7=poly.Polynomial([1,2])
print x7
```

according to above code in python it should print
1 + 2x^2, but it is printing poly [1. 2.]. Please help.

Comment: Why do you think you should get `1 + 2x^2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `numpy.poly1d` and `numpy.polymul`, where the coefficients are `a0*x2 + a1*x + a2`.

For example, to represent `3*x**2 + 2*x + 1`:

```
p1 = numpy.poly1d([3,2,1])
```

therefor for your problem you could use:

```
p2= numpy.poly1d([2,0,1])
print p2
```

and printing p2 will represent:  `1 + 2x^2`